# C++/CLI DirectX11 Pointers removed/Garbage Collected after constructing class

Tags: c++, pointers, directx, clr, directx-11

I'm trying to make DirectX11 work which it does...  except when i leave the constructor of my DX11 class.

I have some pointers to DX11 objects which are all gone when i get to the Clear or Present function.

DX11.h

```
#pragma once

#include <dxgi.h>
#include <d3dcommon.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3d10.h>
#include <DirectXMath.h>

#include "../GraphicsSettings.h"

class DX11
{
public:
    DX11(GraphicsSettings settings, HWND hwnd);

    int errorcode = 0;

    void Clear(float red, float green, float blue, float alpha);
    void Present();
private:
    IDXGISwapChain* swapchain;
    ID3D11Device* device;
    ID3D11DeviceContext* context;
    ID3D11RasterizerState* rasterstate;

    ID3D11Texture2D* backbuffer;
    ID3D11Texture2D* depthbuffer;
    ID3D11RenderTargetView* rendertargetview;
    ID3D11DepthStencilState* depthstencilstate;
    ID3D11DepthStencilView* depthstencilview;
};
```

DX11.cpp

```
#include "DX11.h"

DX11::DX11(GraphicsSettings settings, HWND hwnd)
{
    DXGI_MODE_DESC mdesc = {};
    ZeroMemory(&mdesc, sizeof(mdesc));
    mdesc.Width = settings.Width;
    mdesc.Height = settings.Height;
    mdesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT::DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC scdesc = {};
    ZeroMemory(&scdesc, sizeof(scdesc));
    scdesc.BufferCount = 2;
    scdesc.BufferDesc = mdesc;
    scdesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    scdesc.OutputWindow = hwnd;
    scdesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_DISCARD;
    scdesc.Windowed = settings.Windowed;
    scdesc.Flags = 0;
    scdesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;

    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL fl = D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL::D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0;

    if (D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE::D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL, D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG, &fl, 1, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &scdesc, &swapchain, &device, NULL, &context) != 0)
    {
        errorcode = -5001;
    }

    if (swapchain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&backbuffer) != 0)
    {
        errorcode = -5002;
    }

    if (device->CreateRenderTargetView(backbuffer, NULL, &rendertargetview) != 0)
    {
        errorcode = -5003;
    }

    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC dbdesc = {};
    ZeroMemory(&dbdesc, sizeof(dbdesc));
    dbdesc.Width = settings.Width;
    dbdesc.Height = settings.Height;
    dbdesc.MipLevels = 1;
    dbdesc.ArraySize = 1;
    dbdesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
    dbdesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    dbdesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    dbdesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    dbdesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
    dbdesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    dbdesc.MiscFlags = 0;
    if (device->CreateTexture2D(&dbdesc, NULL, &depthbuffer) != 0)
    {
        errorcode = -5004;
    }

    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC dsdesc = {};
    ZeroMemory(&dsdesc, sizeof(dsdesc));
    dsdesc.DepthEnable = true;
    dsdesc.DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
    dsdesc.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS;
    dsdesc.StencilEnable = true;
    dsdesc.StencilReadMask = 0xFF;
    dsdesc.StencilWriteMask = 0xFF;
    dsdesc.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    dsdesc.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_INCR;
    dsdesc.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    dsdesc.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;
    dsdesc.BackFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    dsdesc.BackFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_DECR;
    dsdesc.BackFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    dsdesc.BackFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;
    if (device->CreateDepthStencilState(&dsdesc, &depthstencilstate) != 0)
    {
        errorcode = -5005;
    }
    context->OMSetDepthStencilState(depthstencilstate, 1);

    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC dsvdesc = {};
    ZeroMemory(&dsvdesc, sizeof(dsvdesc));
    dsvdesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
    dsvdesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    dsvdesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;
    if (device->CreateDepthStencilView(depthbuffer, &dsvdesc, &depthstencilview) != 0)
    {
        errorcode = -5006;
    }

    context->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &rendertargetview, depthstencilview);

    D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC rdesc = {};
    rdesc.AntialiasedLineEnable = true;
    rdesc.CullMode = D3D11_CULL_BACK;
    rdesc.DepthBias = 0;
    rdesc.DepthBiasClamp = 0.0f;
    rdesc.DepthClipEnable = true;
    rdesc.FillMode = D3D11_FILL_SOLID;
    rdesc.FrontCounterClockwise = false;
    rdesc.MultisampleEnable = false;
    rdesc.ScissorEnable = false;
    rdesc.SlopeScaledDepthBias = 0.0f;
    if (device->CreateRasterizerState(&rdesc, &rasterstate) != 0)
    {
        errorcode = -5007;
    }

    context->RSSetState(rasterstate);

    D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport = {};
    viewport.Width = (float)settings.Width;
    viewport.Height = (float)settings.Height;
    viewport.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    viewport.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
    viewport.TopLeftX = 0.0f;
    viewport.TopLeftY = 0.0f;

    context->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);

    float fieldOfView = (float)3.1415f / 4.0f;
    float screenAspect = (float)settings.Width / (float)settings.Height;

    DirectX::XMMATRIX projection;
    DirectX::XMMATRIX world;

    DirectX::XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(fieldOfView, screenAspect, 0.01f, 100.0f);
    world = DirectX::XMMatrixIdentity();
}

void DX11::Clear(float red, float green, float blue, float alpha)
{
    float color[4];
    color[0] = red;
    color[1] = green;
    color[2] = blue;
    color[3] = alpha;

    context->OMGetRenderTargets(1, &rendertargetview, &depthstencilview);

    context->ClearRenderTargetView(rendertargetview, color);
    context->ClearDepthStencilView(depthstencilview, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0);
}

void DX11::Present()
{
    swapchain->Present(0, 0);
}
```

While in the DX11 Constructor the variables are assigned:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3zyM.png

After leaving the Constructor my variables are gone:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GkcV.png

I've had enough by now cuz i already searched for 3 hours and tried 1 hour to fix it with ideas of myself

Comment: Unless you call Release somewhere, it's doubtful the COM references are gone by magic. You're probably not showing your whole code. Please post a Minimal, Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I hadn't implemented Release yet, so this can't be the reason but thanks for trying to help, though i've already gotten rid of it